# Как правильно сделать такое оформление элемента (html/css)?

Tags: html, css, svg

Как правильно реализовать то что на скрине? Лучше средствами html/css, если на край, то svg?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Реализация с помощью `SVG`:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 -50 1400 1400">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="crop" width="100%" height="100%" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <image xlink:href="https://sensum.club/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/r1-1-960x640.jpg" height="1" width="1" preserveAspectRatio="none"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect width="250" height="250" rx="15" fill="url(#crop)" transform="rotate(45 140 200)" stroke="blue" stroke-width="3"/> 
</svg>
```

Answer (score 6):

Тоже на `SVG`, только с радиусом у `rectangle` без `polygon`:

```html
<svg version="1.1" width="130px" height="130px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="a">
      <rect transform="matrix(.72727 -.68635 .73072 .68268 0 0)" x="-171.18" y="54.909" width="114.82" height="114.86" rx="22.016" ry="22.023"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(0,-167)">
    <image transform="matrix(.80714 0 0 .85958 63.93 100.17)" x="-78.619" y="82.7" width="158.96" height="144.6" clip-path="url(#a)" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="https://xakac.info/files/news/8d/a7/Illustration.jpg"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Максим, упс, ну значит не так понял))

Comment: Я тоже не профи, с чего вдруг?=)

Comment: Давай продолжим в SVG_чате=)

Comment: В моём профиле=)) (SVG_chat)

Answer (score 3):

Всё просто,`transform: rotate(45deg)` поможет:

```css
.wrapper {
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.romb {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.romb img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class="romb">
    <img src="https://sensum.club/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/r1-1-960x640.jpg" alt="hi">
  </div>
</div>
```

Пример на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pne7qh00/1/).

**P.S** Просто зеркально нужно будет картинку в фотошопе повернуть. Если будет в этом нужда.

Comment: А если без поворота в фотошопе?

Comment: @MikeRo, тогда легче уже svg=))

Comment: Воспользуйтесь любым сервисом поворота картинок которых в интернете море:) либо в фотошопе.

Comment: @Arthur и примерчик наверное имеется? =))

Comment: http://croper.ru например:)

Comment: @Zicrael да я про svg хотел примерчик =)

Comment: На svg будет очень долго и мучительно рисовать это вручную:))

Comment: @MikeRo, конечно, на что только не пойдёшь=))

Comment: @Zicrael, это мы ещё посмотрим=)) Сейчас за 2 минуты сделаем

Comment: Ну будь по вашему, рабочий пример я привёл.

Answer (score 2):

*ну вот типа так - при помощи топора и синей изоленты*

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}

ul {
  background: #343434;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  margin: auto;
  background: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item1:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150%;
  height: 150%;
  top: -25%;
  left: -25%;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background: url(https://ses-footprint-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/satellite_images/amc-18.jpg) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item1"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: размеры и позицию картинки в :before соответственно подогнать можно